# prevent Visual Studio 2010  from creating auto styles

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I don't want Visual Studio to auto-create styles, when I work in the HTML/ASP.NET desinger.

I've created my own CSS file, but Studio sometimes creates styles itself, which I have to remove for some tables etc.

How can I stop this, where is the setting?

Comment: +1 it has always bugged me, but I never bothered to find out if I can disable it!